# Primes congruent to $k \pmod p$ between $p$ and $p^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Is it true that for any prime $p$, there are primes $< p^2$ which are congruent to every $k<p$?

For example,

$$
\begin{align}
11 &\equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
7 &\equiv 2 \pmod 5 \\
13 &\equiv 3 \pmod 5 \\
19 &\equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I doubt it, but I'll find an example later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be true. But it seems very hard to prove. In [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-216/S0025-5718-96-00763-6/home.html) by Bach and Sorenson, they show that assuming the generalized Riemann Hypothesis, one can show that for each $k \bmod p$, there will be a prime $q \equiv k \bmod p$ with $q \leq 2 (p \log p)^2$, which is a bit weaker than what you hoped to show.

It's unlikely to find a counterexample, and also somewhat unlikely to produce a proof. The best currently known unconditional results are have bounds more like $q \ll p^5$ or so --- these problems are sometimes called *Linnik Problems*.